# Procedural sketch / painting shader

Tags: unity, c#, shaders, animation

So after some google searching apparently I don't even know what this technique is specifically called:

I'm trying to figure out how to create an effect in unity that 'paints' a 2d asset on screen.

By paint, I mean animates brush strokes, eventually 'revealing' the final image. (Start with outlines, then colors)

What is the conventional name for a technique like this, and where would I get started going about creating this kind of effect?

I am not talking about a shader / filter that simply adds a 'painted' or 'hand drawn' effect to an image, but one that simulates actually 'painting' it.

Comment: I've done a simple version of something a bit like this in the past , using a vignette gradient and watercolour-blotchy mask to control the blend weight of the colours flooding underneath the outlines, [looking like this](https://twitter.com/D_M_Gregory/status/797640514724069376?s=19). (You can see a step-by-step breakdown in that thread) Is something along those lines what you have in mind? Or can you point us to an example that more closely matches your intention?

Comment: @DMGregory not exactly, and unfortunately shaders like that are all I can find examples of when I specifically try and search. So imagine taking any still frame from your example, and animate the process of actually painting it, line by line, then filling in with the colors. Closest example would be like the spline-effect in blender to have your text "draw itself" into view.